How to initialize a static reference to another class?
Consider you have one class entity which needs a reference to another class data and you would store multiple of this classes entity in a vector in class data, you might end up with some code like this:
struct data;

struct entity {
    entity(data& _parent) : parent(_parent) {}
    data& parent;
    // some other stuff depending on parents member
};

struct data {
    data(size_t n) : vec(n, *this) {}
    std::vector<entity> vec;
    // some other stuff
};

In order to reduce overhead it would be favorable to make parent (the reference to data) a static member, since all objects of type entity stored in vec have the same reference. Therefore adapt class entity:
struct entity {
    static data& parent;
    // some other stuff depending on parents member
};

But how do I initialize parent now?
Note: I will only create one object of type data in the whole code.

What about objects in different data?

If you have only one data object (let's call it the_data), you can then initialize parent like this: data & entity::parent(the_data);. In this case you have to remove data& _parent from entity ctor. Having said that,  such design is quite awkward.

If there is only one data in the entire program, you can likely remove the reference member altogether and refer to the global singleton that you've made in your code.

@wohlstad, how would you adapt the code? I tried this, but it doesn't work: https://onlinegdb.com/qTXyNy1P7

You could do it like this. But please read the other comments. I doubt this is the best design for your real case.

and yes,  I will only  create one object of type data in the whole code

Then you should take a look at the Singleton pattern. There's no need for entity to have parent at all.

See this demo of using a singleton.

@wohlstad thank you. There is no way moving the construction of data to the main function for dynamic sizeing of the_data?

@PyOPTProblem no because the static member parent cannot be initialized in main. It must be in the same scope as its class (entity) - i.e. global scope.

Posted the information from my comments as a complete answer.

To answer your explicit question:
If you have only one data object you can remove the data& _parent parameter from the entity constructor, and initialize the static parent reference like this:
#include <vector>

struct data;

struct entity {
    entity()  {}
    static data& parent;
    // some other stuff depending on parents member
};

struct data {
    data(size_t n) : vec(n) {}
    std::vector<entity> vec;
    // some other stuff
};

// Initialization of static `parent`:
data the_data{ 5 };
data & entity::parent(the_data);

int main()
{
    [[maybe_unused]] auto& p = entity::parent;
}

Note that the initialization must be done at the same scope as the static member's class (entity) - i.e. global scope in your case.
Live demo 1

However-
If you have only one data object, a more proper design could be to use the Singleton pattern.
Using it there's no need for entity to have parent at all.
Here's an example of applying this pattern in your case:
#include <vector>

struct entity {
    entity()  {}
    
    void some_method_using_data();
};

// This is a singleton:
struct data {
    data(size_t n) : vec(n) {}
    std::vector<entity> vec;

    // Get access to the single instance:
    static data& instance()
    {
        static data s{ 5 };
        return s;
    }
};

void entity::some_method_using_data()
{
    [[maybe_unused]] data& d = data::instance();
    // Use the data singleton d ...
}

int main()
{
}

Live demo 2
This specific way of implementing a singleton is called Meyers' Singleton.
